# Static counter - how to make ID not change [C++]

Tags: c++, static, counter

I'm trying to have a unique ID for every Object created, while also keeping track of how many instances of the object have been created. But it seems like when the destructor is called and the counter is decreased, the ID changes with it.

.h

```
   class Objekt
    {
    public:
        Objekt();
    ~Objekt();

    int ID;
    static int get_counter();

private:
    static int counter;

};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Objekt.h"



Objekt::Objekt()
{
    counter++;
    ID = counter;
}


Objekt::~Objekt()
{
    --counter;
}

int Objekt::get_counter()
{
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a unique ID you need to have two counters: (1) the number of live objects and (2) the number of objects created [to create the IDs].

Your system here is going to create objects with duplicate ids.

Comment: That's a good point about duplicate IDs, the program will only properly apply IDs if no object is destroyed before another is made.

Answer (score 1):

Decouple the idea of the counter from the IDs. Add to the class:

```
static int currentID;
```

And change just the constructor:

```
Objekt::Objekt()
{
    counter++;
    currentID++;
    ID = currentID;
}
```

Counter will now hold the count of alive objects, while currentID will hold the count of all object ever created (also good for getting IDs).

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it ID is actually an object instance number which eventually will get reused and messed up. You may want to switch to use non-decreasing reasonably large (uint64) counter instead or use more realistic ID generated by [::boost::uuid for example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html).

```
class Objekt
{
    public:
    Objekt(): m_id(::boost::uuids::random_generator()()) {}

    public:
    ~Objekt() {}

    private: ::boost::uuids::uuid const m_id;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the destructor is called and the counter is decreased, the ID
>   changes with it.

I suggest you use two counters, ctor and dtor.

```
class Objekt
{
public:
    Objekt()
    {
       ctorCount++;
       ID = ctorCount;
    }

    ~Objekt
    {
       dtorCount++;
    }
    int activeInstances() { return (ctorCount - dtorCount); }
    int maxInstanceId()   { return (ctorCount); }
    int staleInstances()  { return (dtorCount); }

private:    
   static int ctorCount;  // accessible by all instances
   static int dtorCount;  

};



int Objekt::ctorCount = 0;
int Objekt::dtorCount = 0;
```

Now when an instance removed, the ID is not changed and the next ID is always unique.

Note that gaps between ID's can occur.  The number activeInstances() will be correct, but does not compute to a specific ID, nor the max (which is accessible by maxInstanceId()).